# observable subscribe response object scope

Tags: javascript, angular, memory-management, scope

I am trying to understand the scope of rjxs observable response as part of a httpClient call. For example I have a service file which contains the below method,

```
getUserDetails(): Observable<IUserDetails> {
return this.httpClient.get(this.url);
}
```

Now this service method is consumed inside my component as below,

```
this.myService.getUserDetails().subscribe((response: IUserDetails) => {

});
```

Now what will be the scope of response object and how garbage collection happens. Can somebody help me with this understanding please?

Comment: you do not need to worry about garbage collection, and what do you mean with scope? These concepts are abstracted away in javascript. You can of course read in about it with a simple google search :)

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the `response` is the arrow function, which has it as parameter. I mean

```
(response: IUserDetails) => {
   // Scope of response in this block
}
```

The garbage collection depends on the memory management strategy of the JS runtime. We do not have any effect on that from the Javascript code, it is done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no garbage collection in javascript (that you have to worry about). The scope of `response` *inside* arrow function to which it is passed. If you want to do something additional with `response` in your component code like view it in the html template then create a component field and assign it from inside that callback.

Example:

```
user: IUserDetails;

ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.getUserDetails().subscribe((response: IUserDetails) => {
    this.user = response;
  });
}
```